# load data from file in c language

Tags: c, turbo-c++

I'm a beginner. I made a program to load and save data in a binary file, when pressing a load button. But the data displayed in the file is just rubbish data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 5
#define enter 13
#define esc 27 
#define home 71
#define end 79
#define up 72
#define down 80

struct node {
    int id;
    char name[30];
    struct node* prev;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* head = NULL;
struct node* tail = NULL;

void save_to_file();
void display_list();
void append_node(struct node* temp);
struct node* create_node_from_file(int id, char name[]);
struct node* create_node();
int check_for_id(int id);
struct node* search_by_id(int s);
load_from_file() ;

void main ()
{
    char ch;
    int flag = 0, i, num;
    int pos = 0;
    char word[5][30] = {"add", "Display", "Save", "Load", "Exit"};
    struct node* t;
    int id;
    char searchname[30];

    clrscr();
    do
    {
        clrscr();
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            gotoxy(10, 5 + i);
            if(i == pos)
            {
                textattr(0x70);
            }
            cprintf("%s", word[i]);
            textattr(0x07);
        }
  //    textattr(0x06);
        ch = getch();
        switch(ch)
        {
            case enter:
                clrscr();
                switch(pos)
                {
                    case 0:
                        t = create_node();
                        append_node(t);
                        printf("\n\t\tInsertion succeessful !");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        display_list();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        save_to_file();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        load_from_file();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        printf("exit");
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                }

            case NULL:
                ch=getch();
                switch(ch)
                {
                    case home:
                        pos = 0;
                        break;
                    case end:
                        pos = 4;
                        break;
                    case up:
                        pos--;
                        if(pos < 0)
                            pos = 4;
                        break;
                    case down:
                        pos++;
                        if(pos > 4)
                            pos = 0;
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
     } while(flag !=1);
     getch();
}

struct node* create_node() {
    struct node* temp;
    int tryid;
    int t;
    int flag = 0;

    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    while(flag != 1) {
        printf("\n\tPlease Enter Id: ");
        scanf("%d", &tryid);
        t = check_for_id(tryid);
        if(t == 0) {
            temp->id = tryid;
            flag = 1;
        }
        else
            printf("\nId %d already exists!", tryid);
    }
    printf("\n\tPlease Enter Name: ");
    flushall();
    gets(temp->name);
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

int check_for_id(int id) {
    struct node* ptr;
    ptr = search_by_id(id);
    if(ptr != NULL)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

struct node* search_by_id(int s) {
    struct node* ptr;
    ptr = head;
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        if(ptr->id == s)
            return ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

struct node* create_node_from_file(int id, char name[]) {
    struct node* temp;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->id = id;
    strcpy(temp->name, name);
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

void append_node(struct node* temp) {
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
    else {
        tail->next = temp;
        temp->prev = tail;
        tail = temp;
    }
}

void display_list() {
    struct node* temp;
    //sort();
    temp = head;
    if(head == NULL && tail == NULL) {
        printf("\n\tList is Empty!\n\t\tNo Data..");
        return;
    }
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("\n%d", temp->id);
        printf("\t\t\t%s\n", temp->name);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return;
}

void save_to_file(struct node emp) {
    int id;
    int index=0;
    char name[30];
    struct node* ptr;
    FILE* fp;
    //sort();
    ptr = head;
    fp = fopen("file.bin", "wb"); //open file for writing
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        fwrite(ptr,sizeof(*ptr), 2, fp);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    gotoxy(30,10);
    printf("Data saved to file.");
    return;
}

load_from_file()
{
    struct node emp;
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("file.bin", "rb");
    while(feof(fptr) == NULL)
    {
        fread(&emp, sizeof(emp), 1, fptr);
        printf("%d  %s", emp.id, emp.name);
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(fptr);
   //   rewind(fptr);
}
```

What is the problem with the code? And how can I change it?

Comment: Advice: don't use TurboC

Comment: `fwrite(ptr,sizeof(*ptr),2,fp);` --> `fwrite(ptr,sizeof(*ptr),1,fp);`

Comment: There are many issues. For example you call `save_to_file()`, you implement `void save_to_file(struct node emp);`. You are missing at least `#include <stdlib.h>`and `#include <string.h>`. Your code is poorly indented.

Comment: do you understand that a 'binary' file 'usually' does not contain readable characters?

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  There are MANY problems listed by the compiler.  Amongst them, the code is missing the statement: `#include <string.h>`.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: the function: `getch()` can be found  in the (windows only) appropriate MSN libraries. (conio.h) .  usage of that function makes the code non-portable, strongly suggest using something similar to `kbhit()` instead

Comment: when writing prototypes (not the signatures) for functions that will receive no parameters, place `void` between the parens.  Otherwise the compiler expects there will be any number of parameters and generates the code accordingly.

Comment: there are just two valid signatures for the `main()` function:  `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] ).  Note that they both have a return type of `int`.  The visual studio compiler might not complain, but a `void` return type is not valid code.

Comment: as mentioned in a prior comment about `getch()`,  Similar considerations apply for the function: `clrscr()` and `cprintf()`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line 2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the `NULL` is not a single character nor, necessarily, a integer.  Suggest using what you actually meant: '\0'

Comment: unless the I/O from the keyboard is in `raw` mode, the code is not going to see the cursor keys.  And using certain capital letters for cursor actions was found to be a problem some 30 years ago.

Comment: regarding this code: `    clrscr();
    do
    {
        clrscr();` a `do...while()` will always execute the enclosed code at lease once.  to this code results in the function: `clrscr()` being called twice, in a row.

Comment: as a general consideration.  How is the code expected to know that the function: `append_node()` was actually successful?  there are several other similar considerations in the code that are no appropriately handled.

Comment: It is a bad idea to pass a complete struct as a parameter to a function.   Much better to pass a pointer to the actual struct instance

Comment: when calling system functions, like `fopen()` and `fwrite()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the function: `load_from_file()` does not actually load the file, rather it reads the file and echo's it to the terminal.

Comment: in C, the heap memory allocation functions (malloc, realloc, calloc) have a return type of `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and creates problems when performing maintenance on the code.   When calling any of those functions, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the function: `getch()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  This is so the values like EOF can be properly handled.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years due to its' many problems, including allowing the user to overflow the input buffer.  In the latest C standard, it does not even exist.  Strongly suggest using `fgets()